# Converting KML to layer in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, convert, kml, arcgis-9.3

I would like to convert KML to layer, but I did not find the tool (from KML to layer) in the conversion tools in my ArcMap 9.3 version.

What is the issue and how can I solve it?

Comment: what version of arcmap?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: @KHibma I am using arcmap 9.3 version

Comment: The help implies these tools existed in the conversion toolbox at 9.3. But I dont remember that. I thought they only existed from the 3d toolbox back then and moved to conversion in 10.0. So so long ago, I dont recall. This is the only help I can offer: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=layer_to_kml_(conversion)

Comment: @KHibma I believe in 9.3 the conversion was the other way around only (Layer to KML).  That was from my quick look at the help docs when writing up my answer this morning

Comment: Oh you're right. I dont read carefully enough. What I posted is the other way around. That means in 9.3 the only option is a 3rd party solution and there are plenty of questions/answers on that meaning this is basically a duplicate

Answer (score 4):

If you are using ArcGIS 10.0 or newer, there is a tool *KML to Layer* that can be found in the *From KML* toolset in *Conversion Tools* toolbox.

[image]

If you can't find it you can also use ArcMap's Search function (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) and search for `KML` and it should find all the tools that work on KML files including the *KML to Layer* tool (4th in my search results below).

[image]

Note that if you are using an older version of ArcGIS, the *From KML* toolset and *KML to Layer* tool are not available.

Comment: alright,, I am using 9.3 version... so, how can I convert google earth image (KML) using arcmap 9.3 then?

Comment: @Belgacem I can't help you with 9.3 - I haven't used that since 2009/2010 when v10 was released.  I'm using v10.5 now - 9.3 is very old!

Comment: @Belgacem you can use QGIS to load kml file and save it as shapefile or any other desired format. once converted, you can load the shapefile into arcmap.

Answer (score -1):

You can download the free program "DNRGPS". It can import your kml (or gpx and 7 more) at  http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/DNRGPS/DNRGPS.html  After loading, your data can be exported to different formats, one being shp file.  This will be Geographic, WGS84 and you have to set your projection before you go out of DNRGPS (File, Set Projection).  Or 'define projection' in ArcGIS.